# Need help with gdbtui - gnu debugger on linux

Tags: unix, gdb

I ssh into a remote linux sever from my Mac, and run gdbtui to debug a program. The source code displays, but the cursor line in the source code window frequently is not highlighted. I can enter commands such as 'next' and 'list' in the command line window, but the source code window doesn't redraw correctly. It sometimes shows lines in the source file out of order (the line numbers are displayed out of order.)

I have my TERM environment variable set to xterm-16color which vim is very happy to use.  I'm at a loss as to what I should try.

gdb in ordinary command-line mode works fine.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What gdb version are you using? Try the latest one. At least gdb 6.5 had similar problems with tui mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same configuration as you:  I ssh into an Ubuntu server (currently 11.10) from a Mac and I'm currently experimenting with gdbtui.

I recommend that you use [iterm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) as your Apple Terminal replacement.  Besides 256 colors and a ton of other features, it seems to play decently with gdbtui (line highlighting is fine).